# Filtered listview not showing proper data

Tags: android, listview, android-sqlite

## here is my code. I have created filtered listview using SQLite database and json. But when i am searching for data for e.g if name is Shreya Patil then it is only showing me result for name shreya not for her surname. if i am typing patil result is nothing. Please Help..  ##

Here is the snippet from the activity class:

```
public class DirectoryActivity extends BaseActivity {

    private SQLiteDbAdapter dbHelper;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_directory_home_profile);

        dbHelper = new SQLiteDbAdapter(this);

        dbHelper.open();
        //Clean all data
        dbHelper.deleteAllData();
        displayListView();
       getPolicianInfo();


    }

    private void displayListView() {

        Cursor cursor = dbHelper.fetchAllData();
        Log.e("Getting all data", "data");

        // The desired columns to be bound
        String[] columns = new String[] {
                SQLiteDbAdapter.USER_ID,
                SQLiteDbAdapter.POLITICIAN_FIRST_NAME,
                SQLiteDbAdapter.POLITICIAN_DESIGNATION,
                SQLiteDbAdapter.POLITICIAN_CONTACT,
                SQLiteDbAdapter.POLITICIAN_IMAGE_URL,
                SQLiteDbAdapter.POLITICIAN_CITY,
                SQLiteDbAdapter.POLITICIAN_HOUSE,
        };

        // the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
        int[] to = new int[] {
                R.id.directory_item_name_tv_name,
                R.id.directory_item_name_tv_last_name,
               /* R.id.directory_item_name_tv_last_Test,*/
                R.id.directory_item_name_tv_designation,
                R.id.directory_item_name_tv_contact,
                R.id.directory_item_iv_picture,

        };

        // create the adapter using the cursor pointing to the desired data
        //as well as the layout information
        dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this, R.layout.list_item_directory_lv, cursor, columns,to, 0);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.directory_search_lv);
        listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        // Assign adapter to ListView
        listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

        dataAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
            public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
                return dbHelper.fetchPoliticansByName(constraint.toString());
            }
        });


        EditText myFilter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myFilter);
        myFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                          int count, int after) {
            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int before, int count) {
                //dataAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
               DirectoryActivity.this.dataAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);

            }
        });

    }




    private void getPolicianInfo() {

        if (Util.isNetworkAvailable(this)) {
            try {
                API apis = RetrofitClient.getApiClient(Util.DOMAIN_NAME);


                Callback<JsonElement> responseListner = new Callback<JsonElement>() {
                    @Override
                    public void success(JsonElement responseSuccess, Response response) {
                        Log.e("responseSuccess", responseSuccess.toString());

                        if (responseSuccess != null) {

                            Log.e("responseSuccess success", responseSuccess.toString());
                            Log.e("response in success", response.toString());


                            try {
                                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(responseSuccess.toString());


                                {

                                    JSONArray jsonMainNode = object.getJSONArray("posts");
                                    int lengthJsonArr = jsonMainNode.length();

                                    for (int i = 0; i < lengthJsonArr; i++) {
                                        /****** Get Object for each JSON node.***********/
                                        JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);



                                        String user_id = jsonChildNode.getString("id");
                                        String politician_first_name = jsonChildNode.getString("name");
                                        String politician_designation = jsonChildNode.getString("designation");
                                        String politician_contact = jsonChildNode.getString("contact");
                                        String politician_image_url = jsonChildNode.getString("img_url");
                                        String politician_city = jsonChildNode.getString("city");
                                        String politician_house = jsonChildNode.getString("house");

                                        if (politician_designation.isEmpty())
                                        {
                                            politician_designation="NA";
                                            Log.e("Tag2",politician_designation);
                                        }

                                        if (politician_contact.isEmpty())
                                        {
                                            politician_contact="NA";
                                            Log.e("Tag3",politician_contact);
                                        }

                                        dbHelper.createPoliticianInfoData(user_id, politician_first_name,politician_designation,
                                                politician_contact, politician_image_url, politician_city, politician_house);

                                    }
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Network Connection Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Log.e("response in success", response.toString());
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                        Log.e("tag", error.toString());
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Network Connection Failed from failure method", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                };
                apis.getPolicianInfo(responseListner);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Check Your Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    }
}
```

//Here is database class

```
 public class SQLiteDbAdapter {

    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String USER_ID = "id";
    public static final String POLITICIAN_FIRST_NAME = "name";
    public static final String POLITICIAN_DESIGNATION = "designation";
    public static String POLITICIAN_CONTACT = "contact";
    public static String POLITICIAN_IMAGE_URL = "img_url";
    public static String POLITICIAN_CITY = "city";
    public static String POLITICIAN_HOUSE = "house";
    private static final String TAG = "SQLiteDbAdapter";
    private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "World";
    private static final String SQLITE_TABLE = "Country";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private final Context mCtx;

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
            "CREATE TABLE if not exists " + SQLITE_TABLE + " (" +
                    KEY_ROWID + " integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement," +
                    USER_ID + "," +
                    POLITICIAN_FIRST_NAME + "," +
                    POLITICIAN_DESIGNATION + "," +
                    POLITICIAN_CONTACT + "," +
                    POLITICIAN_IMAGE_URL + "," +
                    POLITICIAN_CITY + "," +
                    POLITICIAN_HOUSE + "," +
                    " UNIQUE (" + KEY_ROWID +"));";

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }


        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            Log.w(TAG, DATABASE_CREATE);
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + SQLITE_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    public SQLiteDbAdapter(Context ctx) {
        this.mCtx = ctx;
    }

    public SQLiteDbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
        mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        if (mDbHelper != null) {
            mDbHelper.close();
        }
    }

    public long createPoliticianInfoData(String user_id, String politician_first_name,
                              String politician_designation, String politician_contact,
                              String politician_image_url, String politician_city, String politician_house) {


        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(USER_ID, user_id);
        initialValues.put(POLITICIAN_FIRST_NAME, politician_first_name);
        initialValues.put(POLITICIAN_DESIGNATION, politician_designation);
        initialValues.put(POLITICIAN_CONTACT, politician_contact);
        initialValues.put(POLITICIAN_IMAGE_URL, politician_image_url);
        initialValues.put(POLITICIAN_CITY, politician_city);
        initialValues.put(POLITICIAN_HOUSE, politician_house);
        int cc=(int) mDb.insert(SQLITE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
        //Log.e("insert ", ""+cc);

        return cc;
    }

    public boolean deleteAllData() {

        int doneDelete = 0;
        doneDelete = mDb.delete(SQLITE_TABLE, null , null);
        Log.w(TAG, Integer.toString(doneDelete));
        return doneDelete > 0;

    }


    public Cursor fetchPoliticansByName(String inputText) throws SQLException {
        Log.w(TAG, inputText);
        Cursor mCursor = null;
        if (inputText == null  ||  inputText.length () == 0)  {
            mCursor = mDb.query(SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                            USER_ID, POLITICIAN_FIRST_NAME,POLITICIAN_DESIGNATION,
                    POLITICIAN_CONTACT,POLITICIAN_IMAGE_URL,POLITICIAN_CITY,POLITICIAN_HOUSE},
                    null, null, null, null, null);
        }
        else {
            mCursor = mDb.query(true, SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                            USER_ID, POLITICIAN_FIRST_NAME,POLITICIAN_DESIGNATION,
                    POLITICIAN_CONTACT,POLITICIAN_IMAGE_URL,POLITICIAN_CITY,POLITICIAN_HOUSE},
                    POLITICIAN_FIRST_NAME + " like '" + inputText + "%' OR "
                           /* + POLITICIAN_LAST_NAME + " like '"+inputText+"%' OR "*/
                            + POLITICIAN_DESIGNATION + " like '"+inputText+"%' OR "
                            + POLITICIAN_CITY + " like '"+inputText+"%' OR "
                            + POLITICIAN_HOUSE + " like '"+inputText+"%'",
                    null, null, null, null, null);

        }

        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;

    }



    public Cursor fetchAllData() {

        Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                        USER_ID, POLITICIAN_FIRST_NAME,POLITICIAN_DESIGNATION,
                POLITICIAN_CONTACT,POLITICIAN_IMAGE_URL,POLITICIAN_CITY,POLITICIAN_HOUSE},
                null, null, null, null, null);
       Log.e("Cursor vallue display", "data"+mCursor);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
            Log.e("Cursor vallue display", "datafgdfxg" +mCursor.getCount());
        }
        return mCursor;
    }

}
```

Comment: reduce your example, see also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Add an EditText on top of your listview in its aml layout file. And in your activity/fragment..

```
lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

// Adding items to listview
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_name,    products);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);       
inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    // When user changed the Text
    MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) { }

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {}
});
```

The basic here is to add an OnTextChangeListener to your edit text and inside its callback method apply filter to your listview's adapter.

To get filter to your custom BaseAdapter you"ll need to implement Filterable interface.

```
class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    public View getView(){
    ...
    }
    public Integer getCount()
    {
    ...
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {

        Filter filter = new Filter() {

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

                arrayListNames = (List<String>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                ArrayList<String> FilteredArrayNames = new ArrayList<String>();

                // perform your search here using the searchConstraint String.

                constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                for (int i = 0; i < mDatabaseOfNames.size(); i++) {
                    String dataNames = mDatabaseOfNames.get(i);
                    if (dataNames.toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString()))  {
                        FilteredArrayNames.add(dataNames);
                    }
                }

                results.count = FilteredArrayNames.size();
                results.values = FilteredArrayNames;
                Log.e("VALUES", results.values.toString());

                return results;
            }
        };

        return filter;
    }
}
```

Inside perfromFiltering() you need to do actual comparison of the search query to values in your database. It will pass its result to publishResults() method.